# Getting Null Pointer Exception while taking input by using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, nullpointerexception

Take a look in below code

```
newDriver.findElement(By.name("IDToken1")).sendKeys("2018713");
```

this statement is not working..
coding is fine. But still it fail to take data.
Is there any problem on website?
exception got,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Maybe you are searching by.name and the identification have a IDToken, is the name property correct? you should add more information, e.g. the html code.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to check the following:

1. Check if **`newDriver`** is the only instance of **`WebDriver`** interface that exists within your program when this line of code is executed.
2. Ensure that **`newDriver`** is not initialized **`locally`** within a method and simultaneously initialized **`globally`** within the Class scope.
3. As you mentioned in your comment that you are accessing the same **`WebDriver`** instance i.e. **`newDriver`** you need to write a constructor in that class as :

   ```
   //declare the webDriver instance
   WebDriver driver;

   //constructor
   public method_name(WebDriver newDriver)
   {
       this.driver=newDriver;
   }
   ```

Comment: private static WebDriver newDriver;
I have declare webdriver only once.

Comment: @Raj Are you calling it from any other class?

Comment: Actually I am not able to get that how this problem has occurred. Previously I did not face that type of problem.